# Parentheses signification in the function map (OCaml)

Tags: dictionary, ocaml, parentheses

I have a simple fonction that represents the function map :

```
let f a b = fold_right (fun x y -> a(x)::y) b []
```

I would like to know the signification of the parentheses for  a(x)::y

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the parentheses around the `x` or around the `fun`?

Comment: The parentheses around the x

Comment: I don't think they're necessary. Works for me w/o parentheses. For clarity, I would probably write 'fold_right (fun x y -> (a x)::y) b []'.

Comment: The parenthesis are there for readability. Some people have a gluttony for parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses around `x` in `a(x)` don't have any significance - they're entirely redundant. The author of the code could just as well have written:

```
let f a b = fold_right (fun x y -> a x :: y) b []
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the precision that I needed to have better comprehension of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you often encounter is dealing with pairs of lists of pairs. Artificial example:

```
res, (k, v)::acc
```

means that we return a pair of `res` and an association list `(k, v)::acc`. I usually use (and prefer) the minimal amount of parentheses that capture the meaning, but others advise adding parentheses for readability.

When you compute the pair "on the fly", you don't need any additional parentheses because function application and most operators have higher priority than `,` and `::` -- artificial example:

```
f x, (a x, v+1)::acc
```